# Creating external access to IIS server running in AWS VPC

Tags: iis, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have setup a new instance of Sisense in a AWS windows instance running in a VPC. This runs on top of IIS on port 8081. It is working correctly from the windows VM and I can connect to the app at http://localhost:8081 and http://[private_ip]:8081 but I cannot connect to it from the public IP address either on the server or externally.

From a configuration perspective, I have a VPC with a public subnet. This subnet has an Internet Gateway attached. In the instance configuration I have granted permission to 8081 in the security group to come from any source.

What appears to be happening is the public IP is not passing along the request to the private IP for some reason. Any ideas how to get this working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the instance has a public IP attached (either an elastic IP or not): does the subnet's route table contain an entry for internet access:

```
0.0.0.0/0 via igw-XXXXXX
```

where igw-XXXXXX is your Internet gateway?

Also ensure the local firewall isn't blocking the traffic.